# Handling multiple buttons with same ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I want to populate multiple forms with multiple buttons on PHP loop from mysql. For each entry, I have 3 buttons to be handled with the same ajax calls. The issue I'm facing is to recognize which button is clicked and added it to the form data to be sent for a PHP file

```js
function() {
  var form = $('#PayBillFormForm0'); // will be different for each PHP loop
  var formMessages = $('#PayBillResults0'); // will be different for each PHP loop

  $(form).submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "php/pay.php", // When pay0 button is clicked
        url: "php/decline.php", // When decline0 button is clicked
        data: formData
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        var messageAlert = response.type;
        var messageText = response.message;
        var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + '"style="margin-top:10px;"><d style="font-size:12px; ">' + messageText + '</d></div>';
        (formMessages).html(alertBox);
        $('#Bill0').delay(3000).fadeOut(2000); //Bill0 is different for each PHP loop
      })
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="Bill0">
 <div id="PayBillResults0"></div> <!-- To show Ajax Response Message -->
 <div class="card-header">
  <h1>XXX</h1>  
 </div>
 <div class="card-body">
  <form id="Form0" method="post" action=""> 
   <input name="user" id="user" value="user" type="hidden">
   <input name="id" id="id" value="9" type="hidden">
   <input name="reciver" id="reciver" value="ppp" type="hidden">
   <input name="amount" id="amount" value="333.0" type="hidden">
   <input name="tax" id="tax" value="5.0" type="hidden">
   <input name="comment" id="comment" value="XXX" type="hidden">
  </form>
  <div id="Buttons">
   <div id="Pay"> 
    <button form="" class="btn btn-success" id="pay0" value="pay0">Pay</button>
   </div>
   <div id="decline"> 
    <button form="" class="btn btn-danger" id="decline0" value="decline0">Decline</button>
   </div>
   <div id="Hide"> 
    <button form="" id="hide0" class="btn btn-warning" value="hide0">Hide</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I was able to perform this by labeling each form and labeling each button plus having multiple onclick functions as well as multiple jQuery codes. Any idea how to send clicked button value along with form data to PHP to handle differently.

Comment: The `id` attribute is like Highlander ... *there can be only one!* So you'll need to suffix `id="pay"` with something when you're generating those buttons; the loop iteration for example. You could also target the CSS class `$('.btn btn-success').click( ... )` (though you'll still need to make the ids unique)

Comment: Generating a unique function for each button seems very overkill to me, i'd suggest using [`data-`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attributes for the id, and then later read this attribute to know the id

Comment: @CD001 Or use classes and `$(this)` so you don't need the ID's at all

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - you missed my innumerable edits as I was going along then ;) That occurred to me half a second after I submitted the comment ... though you're right about leaving the **id**s off, that didn't actually occur to me.

Comment: @CD001 Yeah my comment was mainly just about using `$(this)`, I saw where you said they could use classes.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ah Oki - yeah the `$(this)` would be inside the `.click()` method - I figured it was implied in that `...` ;)

Answer (score 0):

When looping with PHP, you should NEVER use any `id` on elements. Use classes instead... Or some [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

You were using unique ids by adding a number to them... Fine. But a class is more useful since you can add one event handler to a class... Instead of `n` event handlers for element created by the PHP iterations. So it avoid useless code duplication and just make sens.

That is what I suggest you now. Modify your PHP loop so it will create that HTML:
   *(I removed all that seemed useless)*

```
<div class="card" data-id="0">
  <div class="PayBillResults"></div> <!-- To show Ajax Response Message -->
  <div class="card-header">
    <h1>XXX</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
      <input name="user" value="user" type="hidden">
      <input name="id" value="9" type="hidden">
      <input name="reciver" value="ppp" type="hidden">
      <input name="amount" value="333.0" type="hidden">
      <input name="tax" value="5.0" type="hidden">
      <input name="comment" value="XXX" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-success pay" value="pay">Pay</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger decline" value="decline">Decline</button>
      </div>
      <div>  
        <button class="btn btn-warning hide" value="hide">Hide</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the `data-id="0"`? That is where you will have your form number using the PHP iteration counter.

Now here is the client-side script to use once (do not loop that):

```
$(document.ready(function(){

  // Change the URL to use with Ajax on button click
  var AjaxUrl = "";

  $(".pay").on("click",function(){
    AjaxUrl = "php/pay.php";
    $(this).closest(".card").find("form").submit();
  });

  $(".decline").on("click",function(){
    AjaxUrl = "php/decline.php";
    $(this).closest(".card").find("form").submit();
  });

  // Form submit handler
  $("form").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var card = $(this).closest(".card");

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    formData.append("formNumber",card.data("id"));

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: AjaxUrl,
      data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      var messageAlert = response.type;
      var messageText = response.message;
      var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + '"style="margin-top:10px;"><d style="font-size:12px; ">' + messageText + '</d></div>';

      card.find(".PayBillResult").html(alertBox);
      card.delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
    })
  });

}); // End ready
```

So on `.pay` or `.decline` button click, the URL to use with the Ajax request is changed accordingly.
*(I don't know the use of the third button)*

Then the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) form submits. And from `$(this)`, which is the `<form>`, you can find all the related elements you need.

Notice that the form number that is submitting is added to the formData.
You'll retreive it with `$_POST['formNumber']`.

Comment: I tried your solution. Everything is fine but for some reason form is not submitting.

Comment: I edited with a small something I missed... `.find("form")` on the button click handlers.