# JQuery Button id Selector is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple buttons to execute different queries. but HTML is not capturing the event although button id is used as selector. I want to hide it and show another button using display blcok

```js
$("#del1").click(function(){
  var del = document.getElementById("del1");
 var confdel = document.getElementById("confdel1");
 del.style.display="none";
 confdel.style.display="block";
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <button form="" class="btn btn-success" id="send1"  style="float:right; width:35%;padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;">Send</button>
  <button form="" class="btn btn-warning" id="request1"  style="float:right; width:37%;padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;">Request</button>
  <button form="" class="btn btn-danger" id="del1"  style="float:right; width:23.5%;padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;">Delete</button>
  <button form="" class="btn btn-danger" id="confdel1"  style="float:right; width:23.5%;padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;display:none;">ConfirmDelete</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("#del1").click(function(){ Correction

Comment: If you click the [edit] link you can update your question to correct the code.

Comment: I made the "correction"... And the snippet seems to work as expected. --- Do you have those buttons multiple times on your page?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have multiple buttons but each with unique id. that's why I'm putting numbers at the end to make sure with php iteration non are the same.

Comment: Ok good... So what's the issue then? You want a single function that will work for them all?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette can you please refer to my old post. Thx https://stackoverflow.com/q/51750143/2514751

Comment: @A.K. Is your button are generated dynamically?

Comment: I answered to your "old post"... Probably making this question useless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using jQuery, and just some cleanup with your IDs. If it's an ID, use `#` in the selector. Since you clicked `#del1`, you can just use `$(this)` in the method. jQuery has show/hide methods, which simplify handling the css.

```
$('#del1').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('#confdel1').show();
});
```